# Trigger Ajax on first click only

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to call ajax only on the first click to save bandwith coz the data is huge. Below is my code

```
$('.id-list').click(function() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "timesheet.php?action=idlist",
    async: false,
    success: function(rdata) {
             $('.id-list').removeClass('id-list') //remove the class
    }
})      
})
```

Inspecting the element, `class="id-list"` was removed, but when i click it again, it triggers the ajax call again which I dont want to happen.

Is there any way to implement this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**or**

API `.one`: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element.

```
   $('.id-list').one('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "timesheet.php?action=idlist",
    async: false,
    success: function(rdata) {
             $('.id-list').removeClass('id-list') //remove the class
    }
})      
})
```

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/one/

**Description:** Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element.

```
$('.id-list').one("click",function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "timesheet.php?action=idlist",
    async: false,
    success: function(rdata) {
             $('.id-list').removeClass('id-list') //remove the class
    }
  })      
})
```

Answer (score 0):

http://api.jquery.com/live/

```
$('.id-list').live("click", function(){
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "timesheet.php?action=idlist",
    async: false,
    success: function(rdata) {
         $('.id-list').removeClass('id-list') //remove the class
    }
})
});
```

Comment: Live is deprecated and not really applicable here even though it might work when removing the class